# How do I run headful puppeteer in a server?

Tags: ubuntu, puppeteer, digital-ocean

I want to run puppeteer with `headless = false` in my Digital Ocean server with Ubuntu.

When I go into the Digital Ocean console on digitalocean.com it runs properly (I have ubuntu-desktop as a GUI, chromium actually pops up and starts running in GUI).

However, when I ssh into the console and try to run the same program the program works until it hits the puppeteer script and I get the following error messages from puppeteer:

`Error: Failed to launch the browser process!`

`Unable to open X display.`

`NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!`

`Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly`

Here's what I've got in my puppeteer config:

```
import puppeteer from "puppeteer";

export const getBrowser = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: [
      "--no-sandbox",
      "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
      "--window-size=1600,1200",
    ],
    defaultViewport: null,
  });
  return browser;
};
```

I've played with removing the `--no-sandbox` and `--disable-setuid-sandbox` but that didn't solve it.

If you're asking yourself "why would they do that?" - it's mainly because I've found the sites I am mining tend to notice less when it's in a headful state (I suppose I could move back to puppeteer-stealth).

Comment: Hey, did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: It was a long time ago so I don't totally remember but I think I ended up deploying Playwright (instead of just plain Puppeteer) using the Playwright Docker image and it worked. I forget if I ran it headful or not and I've completely lost the code, but I'm pretty sure it was headful.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question. I half-solved it. I enabled X11 forwarding in my terminal and now everything launches. However, I still am struggling with it, because I wanted to run headful scripts automatically on my server without me interfering, and now I'm thinking the ways I could accomplish that.